# Plotting different quantiles in ggplot line chart - group command doesn't work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot different quantiles of one variable (in my case "deposit ratio"). I used the same code when I plotted the net margins of banks of different countries (e.g. the countries were the relevant groups). However, when I try to do the same for quantiles it does not work.

I created the quantiles widh dplyr function ntile:

```
DiD$quantile <- ntile(DiD$deposit_ratio,4)
```

And the ggplot as:

```
ggplot(DiD, aes(x=fiscalyear, y=net_margin, col=quantile, group=quantile))+
  geom_line()
```

But the graph looks weirdly like this:

[image]

This is how my dataset looks like:

```
  > str(DiD)
'data.frame':   15962 obs. of  48 variables:
 $ institutionid            : int  4253021 1020106 4257027 4253021 1020106 1020106 4253021 4213277 4189302 4253021 ...
 $ fiscalyear               : int  2010 2010 2010 2011 2011 2012 2012 2012 2012 2013 ...
 $ institutionname          : chr  "Mediobanca International (Luxembourg) S.A." "Vuvuzela 2 Luxco S.A." "European Financial Group EFG (Luxembourg) S.A." "Mediobanca International (Luxembourg) S.A." ...
 $ Tier 1 Ratio             : num  12.26 14.98 9.89 13.52 15.24 ...
 $ snlindustryid            : int  28 1 1 28 1 1 28 1 28 28 ...
 $ snlindustryname          : chr  "Other Banking" "Bank" "Bank" "Other Banking" ...
 $ countryname              : chr  "Luxembourg" "Luxembourg" "Luxembourg" "Luxembourg" ...
 $ Interest Income          : num  230001 52724 6953384 191282 50340 ...
 $ Net Interest Income      : num  45798 41207 3018657 44104 41830 ...
 $ Operating Revenue        : num  65294 62718 3868441 72052 65368 ...
 $ Provision for Loan Losses: num  2791 28543 1683660 -590 16912 ...
 $ Compensation and Benefits: num  974 22825 1411888 1322 26407 ...
 $ EBIT                     : num  243620 2706 3266566 209766 9198 ...
 $ Net Income befoire Taxes : num  59417 -8811 -668161 62588 688 ...
 $ Provision for Taxes      : num  12630 -3895 54354 12333 -589 ...
 $ Net Income               : num  46787 -4916 -766264 50255 1276 ...
 $ Interest Expense         : num  184203 11517 3934727 147178 8510 ...
 $ Other Noninterest Income : num  167 13957 123292 612 15769 ...
 $ Noninterest Income       : num  19496 21552 849784 27948 23538 ...
 $ Other Expenses           : num  2113 20203 985008 8730 21361 ...
 $ Operating Expense        : num  3088 43027 2396896 10053 47768 ...
 $ Cash                     : num  1489298 140820 14818861 1108902 149763 ...
 $ Total Securities         : num  1749025 170150 33217156 1433278 245914 ...
 $ Total Gross Loans        : num  5101847 798445 87148632 5378768 796187 ...
 $ Loan Loss Reserves       : num  2276 33359 3092897 1855 28720 ...
 $ Total Net Loans          : num  5099571 765086 84055736 5376912 767467 ...
 $ Total Intangible Assets  : num  0 0 1561694 0 0 ...
 $ Fixed Assets             : num  3.98 1.49e+04 1.73e+06 2.78 1.50e+04 ...
 $ Total Assets             : num  8.52e+06 1.14e+06 1.38e+08 7.93e+06 1.23e+06 ...
 $ Total Deposits           : num  715630 973073 75024960 737367 1064645 ...
 $ Senior Debt              : num  3493358 41833 40598748 2278582 33456 ...
 $ Total Debt               : num  3493358 41833 41254976 2278582 33456 ...
 $ Total Liabilities        : num  8.30e+06 1.02e+06 1.29e+08 7.65e+06 1.10e+06 ...
 $ Net Debt                 : num  2004059 -98987 26436116 1169679 -116308 ...
 $ Total Equity             : num  220757 122899 8902187 282042 130529 ...
 $ Nonperforming Loans      : num  147367 60893 6103600 124058 66247 ...
 $ Total Subordinated Debt  : num  0 0 656230 0 0 ...
 $ net_margin               : num  0.898 5.161 3.464 0.82 5.254 ...
 $ time                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ treatment                : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ loan_to_assets           : num  0.599 0.699 0.633 0.678 0.646 ...
 $ credit_risk              : num  0.000547 0.035748 0.019319 -0.00011 0.021242 ...
 $ log_assets               : num  16 13.9 18.7 15.9 14 ...
 $ equity_ratio             : num  0.0259 0.1076 0.0646 0.0356 0.106 ...
 $ fee_prof                 : num  0.229 1.887 0.617 0.352 1.911 ...
 $ RoA                      : num  0.549 -0.43 -0.556 0.634 0.104 ...
 $ deposit_ratio            : num  0.0862 0.9545 0.5824 0.0964 0.9667 ...
 $ quantile                 : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 4 1 1 4 4 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(DiD)`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple observations of net_margin per year and per quantile/rank, ggplot connects all (invisible) data points within one year with a line. Could it be that this explains the 'range' of the lines you see within each year?

You might need to stratify by more variables in order to get rid of the sawtooth shape? Or change to geom_pointrange/boxplot etc?